# Table centering with multicolumn

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, multicolumn

For a document, I've been preparing a consonant chart:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}r*{10}{c}}
\toprule

&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Labial} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Alveolar} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Palatal} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Velar} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Glottal} \\ \midrule

Nasal       & mh & m & nh & n                &     &     &    &   &    &   \\
Stop        & p  & b & t  & d                &     &     & k  & g &    &   \\
Sibilant    &    &   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{s} &     &     &    &   &    &   \\
Fricative   & f  & v & th & dh               & c   &     &    &   & xh & x \\
Approximant &    &   &    &                  &     & j   & wh & w &    &   \\
Lateral     &    &   & lh & l                &     &     &    &   &    &   \\
Trill       &    &   & rh & r                &     &     &    &   &    &   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Compiling this code with `pdflatex` yields the following output 
(the gray area is just the background of my PDF viewer):

[image]

My question is very simple: why is the `s` off centered?

Comment: it is perfectly centered, but column have different width, so you have impression, that is not centered ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Do you have now impression, that it is centered?

I suggest to use `tabularx`, which provide equal width columns

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mcbf[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\bfseries}r*{10}{C}}
\toprule
            & \mcbf{Labial} & \mcbf{Alveolar} & \mcbf{Palatal} 
                                        & \mcbf{Velar} & \mcbf{Glottal}    \\
Nasal       & mh & m & nh & n                &     &     &    &   &    &   \\
Stop        & p  & b & t  & d                &     &     & k  & g &    &   \\
Sibilant    &    &   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{s} &     &     &    &   &    &   \\
Fricative   & f  & v & th & dh               & c   &     &    &   & xh & x \\
Approximant &    &   &    &                  &     & j   & wh & w &    &   \\
Lateral     &    &   & lh & l                &     &     &    &   &    &   \\
Trill       &    &   & rh & r                &     &     &    &   &    &   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I added `|c|` to visualize the borders of the cells. I **added an invisible space** (`\hspace{<some length>}`) in order to center the **s**. It's a manual solution and not as good as the solution from **Zarko**.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}r*{10}{|c|}}
\toprule

&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Labial} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Alveolar} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Palatal} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Velar} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Glottal} \\ \midrule

Nasal       & mh & m & nh & n                &     &     &    &   &    &   \\
Stop        & p  & b & t  & d                &     &     & k  & g &    &   \\
Sibilant    &    &   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ \textcolor{red}{\bfseries\dotfill}  } &     &     &    &   &    &   \\
Fricative   & f  & v & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ \textcolor{red}{\bfseries s\hspace{0.4em}}}                & c   &     &    &   & xh & x \\
Approximant &    &   &    &                  &     & j   & wh & w &    &   \\
Lateral     &    &   & lh & l                &     &     &    &   &    &   \\
Trill       &    &   & rh & r                &     &     &    &   &    &   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (≥ 6.0 of 2021-08-10).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\bfseries}r*{10}{X[c]}}
\toprule
\RowStyle{\bfseries}
            & \Block{1-2}{Labial} && \Block{1-2}{Alveolar} && \Block{1-2}{Palatal} 
            && \Block{1-2}{Velar} && \Block{1-2}{Glottal} \\
Nasal       & mh & m & nh & n \\
Stop        & p  & b & t  & d            &     &     & k  & g &    &   \\
Sibilant    &    &   & \Block{1-2}{s}    &     &     &    &   &    &   \\
Fricative   & f  & v & th & dh           & c   &     &    &   & xh & x \\
Approximant &    &   &    &              &     & j   & wh & w &    &   \\
Lateral     &    &   & lh & l \\
Trill       &    &   & rh & r \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]